# Wild characters in parameters of Unix Script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Hi I have an unix  script with 5 parameters.One of the parameters except the name of import_sources,which is passed as "ABC_DJ " or "DEF_DJ" etc now i want the script to accept all the parameters ending with "DJ" like by using something like "%DJ" which will accept the names of all the import_sources with the names ending with "DJ" .

So how can i pass argument in that manner?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide us with a [mcve], so we can understand what you mean more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I think it could be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function select_params() {
  echo $@ \
    | awk -F" " '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i;}' \
    | awk -v name=$suffix '{regex=name"$"; if($0 ~ regex) print $0;}'
}

suffix="DJ"
select_params "$@"
```